# Why did Biggs tell Porkins to eject during the Battle of Yavin?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

In *Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope*, the following exchange [takes place](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGwYj4AqB6Q):

> **PORKINS:**  *I've got a problem here*.
> **BIGGS:**  *Eject.*

I don't understand how ejecting would be preferable to being killed outright. If the mission failed, the Rebel attack fleet would presumably be routed or entirely destroyed, and the ejected pilot would be left to wait around until he was spotted by the Imperial forces and, I assume, killed on the spot.

A rescue also seems totally out of the question - before the photon torpedoes enter the exhaust port, all resources have to be directed at getting a torpedo into the port, not rescuing stranded pilots. Once the torpedo enters the exhaust port, there simply isn't time for a rescue.

**This being the case, why would anyone suggest ejecting?**

Comment: You're mistaking the Death Star for a moon. If Porkins ejects, it'll be into space. He can then make a run for Yavin, hopefully gaining enough distance to be outside the blast radius of the Death Star.

Comment: @Richard -  That illustration seems to confirm the idea that the pilot is basically choosing to die of asphyxiation and/or exposure in space rather than incineration in his fighter.

Comment: @WadCheber -  I think the illustration is showing that a small shield is formed around the seat (that blue light) - also iirc correctly, the Truce at Bakura (now a Legends book) starts with either Wedge or Luke ejected from an X-Wing and floating in space waiting for rescue

Comment: Maybe Biggs is giving the order out of reflex/habit? Alternatively, maybe he's thinking 98% chance of death in what appears to be a shielded ejector seat beats 100% chance if he stays on target?

Comment: related, possible dupe: [How do ejection systems operate for Rebel pilots?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68942/5184)

Comment: Not a dupe, in my opinion, since none of the answers tells us anything about the X-Wing - quite the contrary, in fact:  "A similar ejection mechanism may exist for the X-wing, where the entire cockpit is ejected. I can't find canon to support this notion aside from Biggs' quote and the ejection harness, though. Below is a cross section of an X-wing, which does not show any ejection mechanism."

Comment: Biggs hated Porkins, always sweeping nachos crumbs from his control panel.

Comment: To me, the bigger question is: if SW fighters do have ejection capabilities, why does nobody every use them? Every single battle in every single movie sees all the shot-down fighter pilots going down with their ships. Surely if they had an eject function, there would have been at least some of them that would have been able to use it?

Comment: I've removed the bits that suggest that ejecting wouldn't be possible (since the duplicate Q&A addresses that) and left in the bit about why Porkins might eject, since that's answerable

Comment: Not an in-universe answer, but many scenes in Star Wars were inspired by Tora Tora Tora. The scene with Porkins crashing is likely inspired by a similar crash into a hanger during the attack on Perl Harbor. Compare https://youtu.be/KaRI8mrFtUc?t=85 with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUHtUoP_d_M

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Canonically, we don't currently know, however, in the Legends continuity, "[Magnetic Fields](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Magnetic_field)" were used to create temporary atmospheres.

Emphasis mine:

> Magnetic fields were used throughout the galaxy to contain the atmosphere within starship hangars, **as well as to protect pilots who were forced to abandon their vehicles while in realspace** and did not have the benefit of environmental or vac-rated life-support enviro-suits.

If he can survive the destruction of his X-Wing, *there's a chance* he'll be rescued. A small chance is better than no chance.

Comment: I hear eJECT, but +1 for thinking outside the box, and for having any idea what Porkins' first name was

Comment: PORKINS   
I’ve got a problem here… my converter is running wild…   

BIGGS   
Eject, eject, Blue Six, do you read?    

PORKINS   
I’m all right. I can hold it. Give me a little room, Biggs.   

- Revised fourth draft of the script.

Comment: @WadCheber Edited.

Comment: So he was calling _Blue Six_ to rescue him?

Comment: @SQB - at that point in the script development, Porkins *was* Blue Six, and Wedge was Blue Three.  They later became Red Six and Red Three respectively. "BLUE LEADER (V.O.)
Break off, Luke. Acknowledge. We’ve hit too much interference. Luke, I repeat, break off! I can’t see him. Blue Six, can you see Blue Five?

WEDGE (V.O.)
I’ve lost Luke. There’s a heavy fire zone on this side. My scanner’s jammed. Blue Five, where are you? Luke, are you all right.

BIGGS (V.O.)
He’s gone. No wait. There he is. Fin damage, but Luke’s all right. The kid’s fine."

Answer (score 3):

This was addressed by Leland Chee (AKA Lobot) in *[Star Wars Insider #102](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_102)*. In brief, there's a slim chance that portly Porkins might get rescued and live to fight another day. A thin prospect of survival is better than no chance at all.

> **Q. In A New Hope, Biggs suggests that Porkins eject from his X-wing. Had he been able to do so, how would Porkins have survived in space and escaped the battle?**
>
> **Ask Lobot:** Anyone who saw poor "Goose" buy it in *Top Gun* knows that ejecting from any fighter craft in the heat of battle is a risky proposition but yes, the X-wing is equipped with an ejection system. Of course, had he survived the launch of the ejection seat he would have had to pray that an Alliance retrieval vehicle would arrive to pick him up. The likelihood of that happening, with space around the Death Star crawling with TIE Fighters and about 20 minutes to go before Luke blows the Death Star to smithereens are probably worse than the odds of successfully navigating an asteroid field.