# Whose helmet did Rey put on?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

In *The Force Awakens*, while having her meal next to a fallen AT-AT, Rey put on a rebel pilot helmet. Whose was it? It seemed to have *"Ræh"* written on it, in Aurebesh... Did the helmet belong to someone she adopted her name from?

[image]

Comment: http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2015/12/22/the-mysterious-helmet-in-force-awakens-belongs-to.aspx

Comment: Oh, I thought she wrote her own name on it...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The helmet belongs to a rebel pilot called Captain [**Dosmit Ræh**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dosmit_R%C3%A6h), a member of an elite fighter squadron called the [Tierfon *Yellow* Aces](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tierfon_Yellow_Aces), hence the instantly recognisable yellow sigil.

Her X-Wing, (callsigned 'Yellow-4') crash-landed on the planet during the [Battle of Jakku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku) and was salvaged by Rey along with a variety of survival gear items found in her ship's storage locker.

[image]
<sub><sup>Image courtesy of [Force Awakens Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>

There's also a mention in [Rey's Survival Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rey%27s_Survival_Guide)

[image]

Beyond that, nothing is known of Captain Ræh other than that her ship crashed on Jakku. The fact that her ejector seat had been fired (and that the canopy was missing from her X-Wing and that her helmet was found at the crash site) strongly indicates that she almost certainly survived the initial impact.

[image]

---

Matt Matrin of the Lucasfilm Story Group has confirmed (sorta) that the name Rey has nothing to do with the helmet.

> **MM:** *If she [Rey] could read the name on the helmet enough to name herself, why would she change the spelling?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/946847151765700609)</sup></sub>

Comment: I think this is the better answer, the other answer basically just repeats what the OP said in the question and doesn't actually provide any evidence as to why it is Dosmit Raeh's helmet.

Comment: @theonlygusti - I thought so too :-)

Comment: @theonlygusti, the question asked who's helmet it was, not as to why it Rey had it or any other reason. I provided a clear reason as to who's helmet it was. All the information in my post is in Valorium's post, just with different picture's.

Comment: @KyloRen - I think theonlygusti is probably concerned about the fact that the majority of your answer is secondary sources whereas mine mainly focused on primary sources; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/primary-sources-vs-wikis

Comment: @KyloRen you said: "I provided a clear reason as to who's helmet it was" - no you didn't, many people might have had the surname Ræh, it might have been a tribute to Ræh, it might have simply been badly translated Aurebesh. Simply having "Ræh" written on a helmet doesn't make it _**Dosmit**_ Ræh's helmet. You say also: "All the information in my post is in Valorium's post" - the converse of which is not true, i.e. Valorum adds more information than you have, and actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: @theonlygusti, she is part of the Tierfon Yellow Aces,  which the insignia is also on the helmet which I pointed out as well. There is no other information on that helmet which states that it is anyone's elses.

Comment: @theonlygusti, also , is Rey's survival guide canon? http://www.thecantinacast.net/2016/01/10/review-of-reys-survival-guide/

Comment: @KyloRen - Since it was published after April 2014, the answer is a **very firm yes**.

Comment: @Valorum, I just was not sure it was canon. But I did know that the symbols meant what they meant and that it was Dosmit Ræh's helmet, I did not want to post something that may have been considered non-canon. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @KyloRen - The simple rule is that **anything and everything** published to accompany the new Star Wars films is always totally canon unless it's a typo or a publishing error.

Comment: @Valorum, Ahh, ok. That clears a lot of stuff up.Is there a way of checking this?

Comment: @KyloRen - Yes there is. I put together a handy reference guide [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars). You can also search for the property on Wookieepedia and look to see whether they've marked it as canon or legends. They're usually pretty accurate.

Comment: In-universe answer - if you found a helmet that hadn't been destroyed outright, theres a good chance you found the contents of the helmet too.

Comment: @Criggie - The implication seems to be that she salvaged it along with an X-Wing fighter. No mention is made of bodies (and Rey spends her time as a child imagining Ræh's adventures) so I'd guess she found it *crashed but not inhabited*

Comment: @Valorum  Fair point.  The helmet wouldn't have made it through the atmosphere without being inside a space craft.  The spacecraft made it down safely enough that the helmet survived, whether it was piloted or automated.  So there's not a lot of space on a helmet, but there's more space on a hull. Perfectly reasonable any pilot names marked on the hull were more than a single word - think nose art.

Comment: @criggie - I'm thinking that no matter how (emotionally) attached a pilot was to their helmet, that it's the first thing you'd dump if you had to walk out of the desert.

Answer (score 30):

**The helmet belonged to a rebel pilot named** [**Dosmit Ræh**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dosmit_R%C3%A6h).

The biggest clues is the [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh) writting on the helmet. Link to Canon [Canon Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Template:Canon_Aurebesh)

> In the Outer Rim Territories, Aurebesh was sometimes used alongside
>   Outer Rim Basic, another alphabet.**During the Clone Wars, the back of**
>   **the clone trooper Ponds' helmet had the phrase "Some guys have all the**
>   **luck" written in Aurebesh**

The Aurebesh alphabet translated into English below. I circled the ones on the helmet to make it clearer to see.

[image]

You can see that the helmet has the letters, `Resh`, `Enth` and `Herf` Which translates into ***'RAEH'***.

[image]

I should also mention that the insignia is from the [Tierfon Yellow Aces](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tierfon_Yellow_Aces) which she was a part of.

Comment: @CreationEdge,  Who else had a name 'RAEH' and was a pilot in the Tierfon Yellow Aces?

Comment: @CreationEdge, so where is the evidence that Bobspit Raeh was in the Tierfon Yellow Aces?

Comment: @CreationEdge, hold on a second. I provided canon links to the fact that Dosmit Ræh was a part of the Tierfon Yellow Aces, the insignia is from that. The letters written on the side are '*RAEH*' in Aurebesh. So the only conclusion, (unless you have some other **canon** information that Bobspit Raeh is also in the Tierfon Yellow Aces) is that it is Dosmit Ræh's Helmet. As an aside, do you expect me to post Rey's survival guide after the fact? Valorium posted that info before me, so I can't just edit it in after the fact can I?

Comment: If I don't click the links, there's no evidence. If the linked sites go down, you've got none of the pertinent info here. Just edit it a bit with some excerpts or citations (you don't even mention the books the information can be found in offline), and you're good. Links aren't answers, no matter how credible the data on the other end is.

Comment: You can edit whatever you want into your answer. You can mention Valorum's in yours, too, if you want to give credit. But the sites you link mentioned those as their sources, which is very pertinent to your answer. (I deleted some comments to clean up the thread. Anyway, I'm just trying to help improve your answer with some guidance, sorry for being obtuse to start.)